# Angular HTTP POST - pass a Map structure in the payload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, post

I'm asking myself if is possible to pass a classic Map structrure (javascript/typescript) via http post request.

When I try to do it, I see in browser console (network section) that the request payload present an empty json instead of my predefined map.

In other words, i pass as post payload/model an object like this:

```
  {
     "codiceAzienda": "TEST-CDP",
     "username": "admin",
     "datasource": null,
     "selectionMap": {Map(1) {"home" => Array(7)}},
    "profileList": {"2017" => Array(2), "2018" => Array(2)}
  }
```

But when I see, in the browser, the request payload, it appears like this:
[image]

Is it strange? I'm asking it because is the first time that I try to pass a map in the payload.

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Comment: Maybe, thanks I'll try to make plain objects. 
I'm still curious if map can be passed as payload.

Comment: No, because it can't be serialized, that's why you need to covert it into an object